# IT-/Networking-specific dictionary

Tags: untagged

I am tasked with preparations of technical negotiations with a foreign company where the technicans' native language is Russian. I would like to have a technical dictionary for terms specific to the IT industry, more specifically the networking and management segments to be able to translate things like

- software package
- network switch
- ip address
- settings dialog
- property

into widely-understood and unambiguous Russian counterparts. Where would I ask/look for one?

My trouble with general-purpose dictionaries is that their translation proposals, if applicable at all, often are extremely cumbersome and poorly understood. Anybody who has seen a badly localized application should instantly know, what I mean. And for those who haven't:

[image: broken smoke pipe]

*Is this your idea of a [`broken pipe`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_pipe)?*

Comment: I would look to hire a Russian speaker to do this.

Comment: In soviet Russia, pipe breaks you.

Comment: @Iain the trouble is that it would need to be a Russian speaker *from the industry* who has worked for international as well as Russian projects. It is worth nothing if the person just is able to understand and speak everyday Russian (in fact, I do myself, it does not help me all that much).

Comment: There are Russian's who frequent SF and [unix.se].

Comment: @TomO'Connor [***a different kind of pipe***](http://www.screeninsults.com/images/commando-steam-pipe.jpg), though

Comment: Give @[SaveTheRbtz](http://serverfault.com/users/6244/savetherbtz) a call... maybe he'll do contract work?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but one thing that might help would be to compare translated versions of the same program (e.g. Firefox), since the translations are often done by native speakers with IT experience. If you're in a Linux environment, you can also explore the `gettext` message catalogs in /usr/share/locale. You can view the English and translated version with `msgunfmt file.mo | msgcat -`. This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but if you end up having to do it yourself, it may provide you with some useful words and phrases. GNU coreutils has "Broken pipe" as "Обрыв канала".

Comment: I recently watched an episode of House M.D.(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Pox_on_Our_House) where they needed a Dutch translator, so House paid for a webcam session with a Dutch stripper.  Would this be a possible route? Can't be too difficult to find a Russian speaker..

Comment: Professional translators should be able to do this - especially an authorized bureau. They will have contacts within the relevant industries that can review the texts. It's not cheap, though. If your company isn't willing to pay, you might contact a Russian university - probably some IT students will be willing to help you for less money than the professional translator would require.

Comment: Professionals' bureaus (either translators or just professionals in *other areas* as indicated by @TomO'Connor) are fine if all you need is a translation of a readily-prepared document. It is rather finding the right term in the middle of a meeting or while composing an e-mail I am concerned about - this is where a dictionary, especially one including colloquial usages, would come in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find an online dictionary which has provided me with the basic vocabulary at http://translate.academic.ru

Best of all, it has [passed the "broken pipe" test](http://translate.academic.ru/?q=broken%20pipe&f=en&t=ru&stype=1):
[image: academic.ru translation screenshot for "broken pipe"]

Using `gettext` catalogs in locales in Linux installations [as suggested by @JamesSneeringer](https://serverfault.com/questions/597546/it-networking-specific-dictionary/604592#comment706487_597546) is also an excellent starting point when dealing with Linux-related projects.